# Handling errors in psycopg2 - one error seems to create more?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm using Python 2 with psycopg2 v2.6.2. I'm running a series of psycopg2 commands, and catching any errors:

```
for r in records:
  county = r[0]
  q = 'INSERT INTO allparcels(county, geom) '
  q += "SELECT %s, ST_Union(ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry, 0)) FROM parcel "
  q += "WHERE county=%s"
  print q % (county, county)
  try:
    cursor.execute(q, (county, county))
    conn.commit()
  except Exception, e:
    print e
    print e.pgerror
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

This runs for the first couple of records, then I get `ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` in rapid succession for all the rest of the rows.

Oddly, if I take one of the later commands and run it directly in my database, it works fine. So I think the later errors are something to do with psycopg2 and my error handling, not the SQL command.

I think I must not be handling the error correctly. I'd like my script to print the error, and then continue smoothly to the next command.

How should I do this instead?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue here is the following:

```
try:
    # it is this specific line that causes an error
    cursor.execute(q, (county, county))

    # this never happens, so the transaction is still open
    conn.commit()
except Exception, e:
    ...
    # you never issued a rollback on the transaction ... its still open
```

As you can see, if `cursor.execute` fails then you neither attempt to commit the transaction or roll it back.  The next iterations through the loop will be attempting to execute SQL on an already aborted but not rolled back transaction.

Instead you need to follow this kind of pattern

```
try:
    cursor.execute(...)
except Exception, e:
    conn.rollback()
else:
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

donkopotamus' answer is pretty good. It has a problem in that it rolls back the entire transaction, which could definitely be undesirable behavior if you're executing this query as part of a larger transaction block. In case this query is part of a larger transactional block, consider using savepoints:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("savepoint my_save_point")
    cursor.execute(query)
except:
    cursor.execute("rollback to savepoint my_save_point")
finally:
    cursor.execute("release savepoint my_save_point")
```

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I Got this error when i'm going to insert some data in DB.

This is resolved by ***increasing the size of the attributes*** in the TABLE.